# Dual-Boot Kali Linux and Fedora Workstation 37 Grub Menu Problem

Tags: fedora, grub2, dual-boot, boot-loader

I have **Kali** Linux and Fedora Workstation 37 installed on my machine, and I have been mostly using **Fedora**. I had customized the grub menu for Fedora (Kali grub boot loader was inactive), but after logging into Kali and running the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

I found that the Fedora grub menu had been changed to the Kali grub menu. My installed theme was gone and Fedora was not listed in the grub menu anymore.

I was suggested to run `sudo fdisk -l` on Kali and try other solutions, but I ended up making a bootable USB with Fedora and entering the chroot environment to make some configurations.

Unfortunately, after doing so, I totally lost my bootloader and I don't even have access to Kali anymore. When entering the grub, I receive the following error:

```
error: ../../grub-core/commands/search.c: 315: no such device
error: ../../grub-core/kern/fs.c: 121: unknown filesystem
Entering rescue mode
```

I am new to Linux and I don't know what to do. Can someone please help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but if you a new to Linux you probably [should not use Kali](https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux).It's tools are available for most other distributions.

Comment: Seconding previous. Keep in mind that Kali is a purpose-built toolset for security professionals. If you want to learn Kali, I'd recommend downloading one of the pre-built VMs from https://www.kali.org/get-kali/#kali-virtual-machines. Also it's really important to read the documentation as it's not quite as straight-forward as desktop distributions.

Comment: @Peregrino69 Thank you so much. Yes I want to learn Kali and Cyber Security. I will keep what you said in mind.

Comment: You's welcome :-) I've been told that even the professionals actually often run Kali in a VM instead of directly on hardware.

Comment: Are both installs UEFI or both BIOS/CSM/Legacy? If not sure `[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo EFI || echo Legacy` For more details: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair